# Фильтр по времени

Tags: sql

Имеется запрос:

```
SELECT client, customer, amount, datetime
FROM TRXS
where amount = ‘5000’
```

Необходимо выгрузить клиентов, которые совершали операции на сумму 5000 в минуту. Выгрузить нужно клиентов за весь день. К сожалению, плохо знаю sql и с помощью Between и других операторов не удаётся сделать запрос, который бы выгрузил всех клиентов за день, которые совершали операции на 5000. Выгружаются только за каждую минуту отдельно, что очень долго проверить за 24 часа.

Comment: тип столбца в `datetime` установите и пишите обычные запросы, либо  `<`,`>` либо через `between`

Comment: *все операции с суммой 5000, которые проходили за минуту времени?* Совершенно невменяемый критерий. Поясните, о чём речь - ну хотя бы примером.

Answer (score 0):

Вы не указали ни СУБД, ни как называется колонка, ни какого она типа!
Для СУБД *PostgreSQL* и колонки `time_column` типа
`TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE`:

```sql
SELECT client
     , customer
     , amount
  FROM TRXS
 WHERE amount = "5000"
   AND time_column
       BETWEEN '2019-11-26T00:00:00Z'
           AND '2019-11-26T00:00:59.999999Z'
```

Comment: Спасибо! Но к сожалению запрос выгружает результат именно за 19-11-26 00:00:00 - 19-11-26 00:00:01, а не за весь день, где клиенты в 1 минуту времени перевидали 5000

Comment: @Ekaterina как спросили, так и ответили. Сформулируйте задачу нормально.

Comment: @Ekaterina  Ваша задача была плохо сформулирована.  Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос (нажав «править» под вопросом) и добавьте пример входных данных и пример вывода.